# Can a company force you to use a specific person as a reference in the UK?

Tags: recruitment, applications, references

I just left a small start up company and before I left I asked one of my coworkers if they'd be willing to provide a reference for me when I'm applying for future jobs.  The answer this person gave me was that I had to use the CEO as a reference.  I'm not really sure the CEO would give a very accurate reference since I barely spoke to this person during my time at the company.  The CEO likely also doesn't know what work I did since I never discussed with them what I was working on.  I really think that using the person I originally asked for as a reference would provide a far better and more accurate reference but it seems like I'm not able to do this.  I always thought that you had free will over who you chose as a reference, can they force me to use this manager as a reference?

Comment: Can they force you to use this manager as a reference? They are not forcing you, because you have the option of not using the manager as your reference. Of course, this means that you're getting nobody as a reference but that's your problem.

Comment: If your friend isn't willing to serve as a reference -- due to their understanding of company policy or any other reason -- you can't force _them_ to do so. You might want to check with someone else to find out if that really is the policy -- or you might not want to check, since if you discover that it isn't the policy but your friend still declines that might cost you a friendship.

Comment: Maybe your colleague was just trying not be rude and save your feelings by not saying "no". Thus a polite alternative to no is saying I can't.

Comment: Could be the company is trying to control who speaks for the company - this situation is a bit unusual, but not unheard of.

Comment: It's not clear who you think the 'they' in your last sentence is. Yes you are free to choose who to use as a reference - but only if your chosen person agrees!

Comment: Could it be that the person you asked may not want to give the reference, but may also not want to say directly to you "I don't want to give you a reference". Maybe that's the reason for the "Oh, you have to ask the CEO" response

Comment: @HorusKol in the Uk company's tend only to give  a formal references  you can ask who you like as a personal referee and if your going for a security clearance personal references are mandatory

Comment: Take the not-so-subtle hint that they weren't going to give you a good reference anyway and find someone else to serve as a reference.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is yes - nobody in the company is under any obligation to give you a reference and many larger companies insist on a deferral to HR. Often, they'll only confirm dates.

That said, I'd ask around a little and see if you can find someone more willing to give a personal reference.

It also has to be said that references have become little more than a formality now and are normally conducted at the last stages of recruitment to ensure that your CV was at least truthful about the where, when and what your job title was.

Comment: Utterly agree with the statement about the value of a reference becoming less and less. The last 3 reference requests I received from hiring companies for former staff only asked for confirmation of employment and dates. I kicked these straight to HR for a response.

Comment: It's also worth noting some companies started requesting "official" references. (Basically that your reference is on formal letter head or other means of confirming the source) which is a wasteful exercise since a two minute call to HR will get you the same information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do have free will with respect to who you ask for a reference.  But the company also has the right to decide who speaks on their behalf, and that supercedes your right to ask.  If the company is linked in any way to the reference, than the person providing the reference is speaking as a representative of the company, whether they intended to or not.

You can check to confirm if that really is the policy, but I'm not sure what you will gain.  If it is the policy, you are stuck with the CEO (who you don't want) and if it is not, then what does that say about your relationship with the person you asked?